# Why is an inverse loop faster than a normal loop (test included)

Tags: php, loops, benchmarking

I have been running some small tests in PHP on loops. I do not know if my method is good.

I have found that a inverse loop is faster than a normal loop.

I have also found that a while-loop is faster than a for-loop.

> #### Setup

```
<?php

$counter = 10000000;
$w=0;$x=0;$y=0;$z=0;
$wstart=0;$xstart=0;$ystart=0;$zstart=0;
$wend=0;$xend=0;$yend=0;$zend=0;

$wstart = microtime(true);
for($w=0; $w<$counter; $w++){
    echo '';
}
$wend = microtime(true);
echo "normal for: " . ($wend - $wstart) . "<br />";

$xstart = microtime(true);
for($x=$counter; $x>0; $x--){
    echo '';
}
$xend = microtime(true);
echo "inverse for: " . ($xend - $xstart) . "<br />";

echo "<hr> normal - inverse: " 
        . (($wend - $wstart) - ($xend - $xstart)) 
        . "<hr>";

$ystart = microtime(true);
$y=0;
while($y<$counter){
    echo '';
    $y++;
}
$yend = microtime(true);
echo "normal while: " . ($yend - $ystart) . "<br />";

$zstart = microtime(true);
$z=$counter;
while($z>0){
    echo '';
    $z--;
}
$zend = microtime(true);
echo "inverse while: " . ($zend - $zstart) . "<br />";

echo "<hr> normal - inverse: " 
        . (($yend - $ystart) - ($zend - $zstart)) 
        . "<hr>";

echo "<hr> inverse for - inverse while: " 
        . (($xend - $xstart) - ($zend - $zstart))
        . "<hr>";
?>
```

> #### Average Results

***The difference in for-loop***

normal for: 1.0908501148224
inverse for: 1.0212800502777

normal - inverse: 0.069570064544678

***The difference in while-loop***

normal while: 1.0395669937134
inverse while: 0.99321985244751
normal - inverse: 0.046347141265869

***The difference in for-loop and while-loop***

inverse for - inverse while: 0.0280601978302

> #### Questions

My question is can someone explain these differences in results?
And is my method of benchmarking been correct?

Comment: How many test runs did you do? Are your results consistent across many executions?

Comment: This is an average of about 36 executions of this script. The results were almost every time the same. For every execution I copied the results in excel and averaged them here.

Comment: So... in ten million iterations the difference was... less than a millisecond? You seriously need to consider other parts of the application. Like trying to get rid of such loops in the first place.

Comment: @Billy Oneal: I agree with your statement, but this question is just out of pure curiosity. I have read about this quite some while, I was just wondering why this is.

Comment: My results are not exactly the same. Many times my inverse for was slower than my normal for. And my inverse while was sometimes slower than my inverse for.

Comment: @webbiedave: Strange because I have the exact same results again and again. Can this have something to do with memory or CPU being differently used in our systems. I am running this on a new server with minimal resources used.

Comment: Could be. I was running outside of a web server context on linux on an Intel Celeron 420 @ 1.60GHz. However, I do have many other processes running.

Comment: for would be slightly improved if you took out the assignment: for(; $w<$counter; $w++) ... but ever so slightly lol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the inverse for loop, you're only doing one variable lookup per iteration:

```
$w > 0         // <-- one lookup to the $w variable

$w < $counter  // <-- two lookups, one for $w, one for $counter
```

This is why the inverse is slightly faster.  Also, a while loop has only one operation per iteration:

```
$w < $counter        // <-- one operation while loop

$w < $counter ; $w++ // <-- two operation for loop
```

Of course, you have that extra operation inside the loop's code block, but I'm not sure exactly why that's faster (maybe someone can fill in the blank there).  You'll notice the time difference is minimal, because these operations are still very fast.  Such micro-optimisations are most effective on very large loops.

Comment: Ah I see. Both explanations make perfect sense. But in the first case, If I set the $counter just to 1000000 It is still one look up, but still the same results.

Comment: `$counter` has to be looked up at every loop iteration, not just once.

Comment: Your second case here is a bit off the mark.  Whenever/wherever it's done, `$w` still has to be incremented on every iteration.

Comment: @Saif: do you mean if you swap `$counter` with `1000000` the results are the same, or if you set `$counter = 1000000` the results are the same?  If it's the former, then I'm not sure.  Maybe subtraction is a cheaper operation than addition ;-)  If it's the latter, the variable is still looked up on each iteration (because it's a variable that could be changed from inside the loop).

Comment: @Chris: I did note that, and honestly I'm not sure why it is faster.

Comment: I ment removing the counter variable and just hard code the number. I get the exact same results